# Which of the following about a permutation is correct?? (CSIR-2015, June)

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, solution-verification

Let $\sigma:\{1,2,3,4,5\}\rightarrow\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ be a permutation (one-to-one and onto function) such that 
$$
\sigma^{-1}(j)\le \sigma(j)
\quad\text{for all $j$ such that }1\le j\le 5.
$$
Then which of the following are true?

1. $\sigma(\sigma(j))=j \quad \forall j$, such that $1\le j \le 5$.
2. $\sigma^{-1}(j)=\sigma(j) \quad \forall j$, such that $1\le j \le 5$.
3. The set $\{k : \sigma(k) \ne k\}$ has an even number of elements
4. The set $\{k : \sigma(k) = k\}$ has an odd number of elements

I think that the only possibilities are $2$-cycles or product of such cycles. So the choices are 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Is it correct?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.
The permutation $\sigma\circ\sigma$ preserves the order by your assumption, so it has to be the identity.
Therefore $\sigma$ is a product of 2-cycles.

Comment: consider $\sigma$ as $(23451)$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ will be $(15432),$ this permutation holds the given condition but none of the option holds good.

Comment: @RisingStar, the given condition does not hold for that permutation for all values of $j$. You have $\sigma^{-1}(1)=5>2=\sigma(1)$.

Comment: $\sigma^{-1}$ is $(15432),$ here $\sigma^{-1} (1)$ is 2.

Comment: @RisingStar, some people read permutations in opposite directions; your $(123)$ is my $(132)$. Anyway, sticking to your convention, $\sigma^{-1}(3)=4>2=\sigma(3)$, so the condition still fails.

Comment: $\sigma(3) = 4$

Comment: @RisingStar, I don't think I understand what your $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ are, then. My first impression was that your $\sigma$ maps $2\to3\to4\to5\to1\to2$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ in the opposite direction. This fails the condition at $j=1$. If you want to invert the arrows, the condition fails at $j=3$. Both $\sigma(3)$ and $\sigma^{-1}(3)$ cannot equal $4$ if $\sigma$ is a 5-cycle.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear that $1)\Leftrightarrow 2)$ and $3)\Leftrightarrow 4)$.

We also have $\sigma^{-1}=\sigma$ (why?), so $1)$ and $2)$ hold.

From $\sigma^2=e$ (here $e$ denotes the identity) we deduce that $\sigma=e$ or $\sigma$ has order $2$ in $S_5$. In the latter case $\sigma$ is a transposition or a product of two *disjoint* transpositions. This shows that the set $\{k:\sigma(k)=k\}$ can have five, three, respectively one element, so  $3)$ and $4)$ also hold.

Comment: why do we have $\sigma^{-1}=\sigma$?

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186847/if-f-1j-leq-fj-for-all-j-then-f-f-1).

Comment: :p After  I commented on your post, I was able to show it using induction on my own. I wanted to know the other ways to show the same result. Anyways thanks for taking time and replying. Have a great day!